# How to allow regular user to mount NFS share on macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, mount, nfs, macos-ventura

We have an NFS share on a server.

We can mount this share on macOS Ventura as user "root", but not as a regular user.

Here is the script to mount as user "root":

```
$ showmount -e 192.168.2.12
$ sudo mkdir -p /Volumes/NAS
$ sudo chown regularuser:staff /Volumes/NAS
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,rw,nolock 192.168.2.12:/home/regularuser/NAS /Volumes/NAS
```

Question:

How can this NFS share be mounted by a "regular" user, a user without root privileges?

On Linux this would work by adding the "user" option to the relevant line in file `/etc/fstab`:

```
192.168.2.12:/home/regularuser/NAS /Volumes/NAS  nfs  resvport,rw,user,nolock,noauto 0 0
```

The `user` option was added as above to /etc/fstab.

But then the command
 `mount NAS` says this:

```
mount_nfs: warning: option "user" not known
```

And it does not mount the drive after this.